# var didStopCallback: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil

Tags: swift, closures

```
var didStopCallback: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil
```

"((Error?) -> Void)? = nil"
is that closure?

who know the normal type

I just start learning swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a closure, to be specific, it is an optional closure of type `(Error?) -> Void` that has a default value of `nil`.

Example:

```swift
didStopCallback = { (err) in 
   // If there is an error, do error handling here
   if err != nil {
        print(err!.localizedDescription)
   }

    // Do other completion handling here
}
```